# How to get return Code from Host program triggered from Java Code

Tags: unix

My Aim is to trigger a shell script from java program. Here Shell Script is going to move files from one server to another.

So I used the following Code to trigger the shell script from java program.

```
  try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/destino/workspace/JavaProject/move.sh /"); //Whatever you want to execute
            proc.waitFor();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

In host scripts I am trying to copy a file from one Host to other using scp command.

So is it possible to get the return code from the shell script.

Thanks,
Abhinav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`exitValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()):

```
proc.exitValue();
```

If you need to get output of script use [`proc.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream())